# Triggering Google Now Cards using email schemas: Cards don't show up

Tags: google-schemas, google-now

I inserted schema into an email that confirms an event registration in JSON-LD format. I mailed this to myself using Google AppScript. But I'm unable to see the triggered card in Google Now. The markup has been verified by Google's markup tester and is valid.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context" : "http://schema.org",
      "@type" : "EventReservation",
      "reservationNumber" : "SDCC12345",
      "reservationFor" : {
        "@type" : "Event",
        "name" : "San Diego Comic Con 2014",
        "startDate" : "2014-07-29T08:30",
        "location" : {
          "@type" : "Place",
          "name" : "San Diego Convention Center",
          "address" : {
            "@type" : "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress" : "111 West Harbor Drive",
            "addressLocality" : "San Diego",
            "addressRegion" : "California",
            "addressCountry": "USA"
          }
        }
      },
      "underName" : {
        "@type" : "Person",
        "name" : "Jon Snow"
      },
    "reservationStatus": "confirmed"
    }
    </script>
    <p>
        Dear Jon, thanks for booking your San Diego Comic Con ticket with us.
    </p>
    <p>
        BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
        Order for: Jon Snow<br/>
        Event: San Diego Comic Con 2014<br/>
        When: July 27th 2014 8:30am PST<br/>
        Venue: 111 West Harbor Drive, San Diego,California<br/>
        Reservation number: SDCC12345<br/>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a slightly different structure to mine, but mine has worked. The parts where there are obvious differences are:

1. The order of the elements
2. The reservation status value format
3. The start date value format

The order shouldn't matter, so skip that for now, and try changing your status value to be:

```
"reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed",
```

Then change your Start Date value format to include a timezone, similar to:

```
"startDate": "2015-04-25T15:00:00-00:00",
```

If that doesn't make it work, try ordering your data to the following order:

1. Event type
2. Confirmed status
3. Under Name
4. Reservation For

Cheers,
Conor